# What is the difference between "Build GitHub Pull Requests" and "GitHub Pull Request Builder"

Tags: git, github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am struggling with some of the jenkins build triggers.

What is the difference between "Build GitHub Pull Requests" and "GitHub Pull Request Builder"? are they refer to the same thing?

[image]